# Reading the Echo of a POST Request for Android

Tags: java, android, post, android-volley

Please i really need your help blocked from yesterday :'(

```
// MY X VAR

int x ;
```

// im executing the check_referrer() function into my the button click listner

```
   signupJoinBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            username = signupUsername.getText().toString();
            referrercode = signupReferrer.getText().toString();

            x =check_referrer(username,referrercode);
```

// Check_ Referrer is supposed Reading "1" or "0" from my PHP file ( i tested my php file and his working )

```
public int check_referrer( String referral, String referrer  ) {


String awr = Config.Base_Url + "get/checkref.php";

 final String v1 = "1"; // OK
 final String v0 = "0"; // The referrer is not existing

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,awr,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if (response.equals(v1) ) {

                            x= 1;
                    }
                    else  if (response.equals(v0) ) {

                        x= 0;
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

               // user is the variable my php file will receive
            params.put("user",username);
                // user is the variable my php file will receive
            params.put("ref", referrercode);
            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
```

in your onResponse method. Then you can pull Json values from php file using

```
String var1 = jObj.getString("var1");
```

Can you show us your php file?